# How to redirect the URL/public/language to URL/public

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana, kohana-3.2, kohana-3.3

we are using kohana 3.2 (PHP). Now our website have more language. we will pass the URL/language/public/. This path  must be redirect to URL/public/. can you advise us.

```
en/public/white/css/en_style.css changed to /public/white/css/en_style.css
```

Comment: do you want to redirect all urls?

Comment: yes I need to redirect all the url

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following redirect in .htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/en/(.+)$ /$1
```

This will redirect

- /en/foo/bar

to

- /foo/bar

Change 302 to 301 (permanent redirect) when you are sure the redirect is working fine.

Comment: It is working fine. But i need to redirect only the en/public or ar/public means redirect to /public . Other wise it is working normal.